# How do I solve this combinational problem??

Tags: discrete-mathematics, combinations

I got a problem like below, and cannot solve yet.
I know that if n is odd number, it can be prove, but if n is even number how can I prove it?

[image: Problem]

Comment: Think of $0=(1-1)^n$.

Comment: If you show how you worked this for $n$ odd, that would provide some [context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960), which is usually required for questions here.

Answer (score 1):

$(x+y)^n=$$n\choose 0$$x^n$ + $n \choose 1$$x^{n-1}y$ + $n \choose 2$$x^{n-2}y^2$ + ... + $y^n$$n \choose n$

Put $x=1, y=-1$ and voilà.